# System calls from php

Tags: php, python, c

I'm working on a cloud compiler,
I can compile and run with only one file with the above code snippets.
How can I do same thing more than one c files or python files

```
shell_exec('gcc main.c -o someobjectfile');

$output=shell_exec('./someobjectfile');

$mystring = exec('/usr/bin/python /var/www/public/user-files/burakkoray/test.py');
echo $mystring;
```

Comment: please explain do you have problem in compiling two source files of the same project ??

Comment: reinventing the wheel? https://code.google.com/p/distcc/

Comment: yes exactly; for example what if I have functions.c and main.c

Comment: I'm trying to compile and execute more than one c file via php I have linux server backside @KarolyHorvath

Comment: would you please stop repeating yourself? that's a description of a task. we would like to know, what the *problem* is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have for instance two source files function.c and main.c then to compile them just proceed like that :

```
gcc main.c function.c -o someobjectfile
```

take care here that the two files are in the same directory and if you want to avoid any trouble just add the absolute path for each one

to execute the program then:

```
./someobjectfile
```

Comment: Thank u .your answer very logical I've tried this before. I'm sure about that files are in same directory but I haven't fixed the problem

Comment: try to execute the commands mentioned above in the terminal and tell me what happens ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at one of the simpler build utilities.

make -- the granddaddy of all build utilities --powerful but complex syntax (tabs are significant!)

Cmake -- newer cleaner make used by KDE project

Scons -- sweet system with nice syntax implemented in Python.